# refreshApex not working inside Modal LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, refreshapex

My requirement is, whenever user uploads a file inside Modal, its record should get shown in a table below upload option.

I am able to run 'refreshApex' outside Modal successfully, but when i write the same code inside Modal, it won't work!!

I am not able to understand why so??

On upload finished, i call this method below : (this works outside modal, but isn't working inside modal)

```
 getUploadedFiles(){
        refreshApex(this.ReleatedFiles);
        window.console.log('ReleatedFiles' + this.ReleatedFiles);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show all relevant code or create playground link to understand what you mean by outside/inside modal code?

Comment: @salesforce-sas Outside means - on the Landing page it works.  Inside means - on landing page there is a button, upon which modal gets opened

Comment: Still not clear, can you create playground link